# 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following file:

```
$ head orthoset.cov
87.0
55.4
80.6
56.8
78.4
41.2
44.9
96.7
83.0
67.9
```

However, I failed to to create a histogram with the following code:

```
> chol <- read.table("~/orthoset.cov")
> hist(chol,xlab = "Weight",col = "yellow",border = "blue")
Error in hist.default(chol, xlab = "Weight", col = "yellow", border = "blue") : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You are passing the entire dataframe to `hist`, try passing the column name. `hist(chol$V1)`

Comment: `read.table` will return a data.frame with columns (with a default name of `V1`). Use `hist(chol$V1, ...)`